# trouble updating nav with ajax content

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I've been able to use ajax and php to update all my page, with the exception of the nav content.  It refuses to play along with the remainder of the page.

the nav section in my HTML looks like this:

```
<nav id="nav">
    <div id="nav"></div>
    <ul>
        <li> 
            <a href="">Dropdown</a>
        <ul>
    </ul>  
</nav>
```

My Ajax now looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var frm = $('#picker');
frm.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: frm.attr('method'),
        url: "http://xxxx.com/test.php",
        data: frm.serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#nav").html ( data );
        }
    });

    return false;
});
</script>
```

currently the php should echo "this code works". It's functional if I point it to any other div, but refuses to work if I send it to nav.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  This detail is driving me batty. If I can make this work without editing my css, it would be greatly appreciated.  I'm not so skilled in that area either, so I'm reluctant to edit any of that code, if possible.

update:  I tried removing the   line, with no success.  Removing the line prior to that causes other problems.

update2:  I made some edits per your suggestions.  no luck yet.

```
<nav id="nav">
    <div id="nav2"></div>
    </li>
       <li> 
         <a href="">Dropdown</a>
    <ul>
    </ul>   
    </nav>
```

and editing the Ajax:

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var frm = $('#picker');
        frm.submit(function () {
                   $.ajax({
                          type: frm.attr('method'),
                          url: frm.attr('action'),
                          data: frm.serialize(),
                          success: function (data) {
                           $("#nav2").html ( data );
                          }
                          });

                   return false;
                   });
            </script>
```

Thanks again.

Comment: just for the record dont use the same ids for multiple elements , it's an id for cry sake . and in about 99% thats why it doesnt work

Comment: The opening `<ul>` after the anchor should probably be a closing `</li>`. And yes, identifiers need to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

**More than one ID of the same name isn't allowed in HTML.**
Try removing the `<div id="nav"></div>` and it should work

Comment: I just tired that, with no success.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you require id #nav with your ajax and you have two objects with this ID. remove one, or rename it.

More than one object with same ID is not allowed in one HTML document